# Do not lock on objects with weak identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, reliability

How can i resolve this reliability issue([Do not lock on objects with weak identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290.aspx))?
Should i lock it with "object locker = new object();"?

```
lock (typeof(ObjectCultures))
 {
     if (!requestCache.Contains(GetCacheKey(objectId, cultureId)))
         {
             requestCache.Add(GetCacheKey(objectId, cultureId), responseStr);
         }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, use `object locker = new object()` and lock on that (just be sure locked variable is a shared class member, not a local variable otherwise lock is useless).

Comment: Locking on a type is considered bad practice. Using a lock object is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should lock an `object` not a `type`. Declare and instance this object in a main scope of your class, for sample:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
       lock (_lock)
       {
           // some code
       }
    }
}
```

This code will block all thread that are trying to execute this block and make them wait for finish and then execute the next thread.

Comment: Assuming there are no static resources used within the method, he shouldn't be using a static synchronization object.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new static instance of an object and lock on that:

```
private static readonly object locker = new object();

lock (locker)
{
    ....
}
```

This is on the assumption you are locking inside a static method (due to your use of `typeof(T)` instead of the `this` which is also bad practice).

Obviously if you are inside an instance method remove the `static` from the declaration.

[This](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/lockchoice.shtml) article by Jon Skeet will help explain why the issue is being flagged in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, you need to put the lock in a static object reference. An `object` typed reference should be enough.

```
public class X
{
     private readonly static _syncLock = new object();

     public void DoStuff()
     {
          lock(_syncLock) 
          {
             // Critical section
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how you should lock.. depends on the context, and the bigger picture of code you are trying to write..

What you do want to avoid, is locking on objects of type indicated in the link you already got -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182290.aspx

Do note that the handful of types listed here is not the full list...

• MarshalByRefObject

• ExecutionEngineException

• OutOfMemoryException

• StackOverflowException

• String

• MemberInfo

• ParameterInfo

• Thread

Full list would include instance of any type which is derived directly or indirectly from any of the above mentioned types..
Note that `System.Type` extends `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx
And hence the warning, when using `lock (typeof(ObjectCultures))`